# Setting n_features_to_select RFE as percentage in pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, rfe

I have a pipeline like so:

```
lin_reg_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('polynomial_features', PolynomialFeatures()),
    ('normalize_polynomial_features', StandardScaler()),
    ('feature_selection', RFE(LinearRegression(), verbose=1)),
    ('lin_reg', LinearRegression())
])
```

Now, when fitting this pipeline in a gridsearch I specify the following parameters to tune on:

```
params = {
    'polynomial_features__degree': [1, 2, 3],
    'feature_selection__n_features_to_select': st.randint(10, 100)
}
```

Is there a way I could set n_features_to_select as a percentage of the total amount of features in the dataset? Because I don't know how many features `PolynomialFeatures()` will add.

Thanks in advance,

Kevin

Comment: You can create a wrapper on RFE to convert percentage to numbers to send to internal RFE.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a float between 0.0 and 1.0 as the `step` argument and that will remove a percentage with each step by default.

Check out [the documentation here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFE)